# How can I add units to variables inside Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, units

I've created a Manipulate expression with many variables. I would like each of these variables to have associated units as in the standard Quantity[Value,"Unit"] so that I can easily enter the values I want and get the answer in correct units. Unfortunately, Manipulate doesn't seem to tolerate this regardless of where I try to insert this feature. I'd also like to add UnitConvert to the answer so that I can see it in "mL/min".

```
Manipulate[
  (Pi*(d/2)^2*c*e^3*Rb^2)*((3*(1 - e)*0.0728*Cos[t])/(e*L*Rb)+9800*Sin[p]))/((1 - e)^2*0.00089),
     {{L, 0.07, "wick length"}, 0.01, 0.1},
     {{d, 0.0068, "wick diameter"},0.001, 0.008},
     {c, 1/60, 1/30},
     {{e, 0.5, "porosity"}, 0.3, 0.9},
     {{Rb, 0.0001, "fiber radius"}, 0.00001, 0.0002},
     {{t, 70*(Pi/180), "contact angle"},0, Pi/2},
     {{p, Pi/2, "wick orientation"}, 0, Pi/2}]
```

I've already tried replacing the bounds on each variable with quantities. And I've tried defining the symbols as quantities before entering the manipulate expression. I've also tried adding Quantity[] to each variable within the math expression. None of these works. Please help, there must be a way to do this, right?!

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the parentheses - this doesn't run.

Comment: But `Quantity` inside `Manipulate` works, for example `Manipulate[Pi Quantity[r, "Meters"]^2, {{r, 1., "radius"}, 1, 10}]`

Comment: Thanks, I modified my original code, so I may have misplaced a parentheses. I've since gotten a good explanation of where I went wrong in my Quantity syntax via the Mathematica community.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct syntax for using Quantity in Manipulate.

```
γ = ChemicalData["Water", "SurfaceTension"];
μ = ChemicalData["Water", "Viscosity"];
ρ = ChemicalData["Water", "Density"];
g = Quantity["StandardAccelerationOfGravity"];

darcyEqn[d_, c_, ϵ_, Rb_, 
   L_, θ_, ϕ_] := ((Pi (d/
          2)^2 c ϵ^3 Rb^2)/((1 - ϵ)^2 μ)) (((3 \
(1 - ϵ) γ Cos[θ])/(ϵ L Rb)) + 
     g ρ Sin[ϕ]);

Manipulate[
 UnitConvert[
  darcyEqn[d Quantity[1, "Millimeters"], c, ϵ, 
   Rb Quantity[1, "Microns"], 
   L Quantity[70, 
     "Millimeters"], θ °, ϕ °], 
  "mL/min"], {{L, 70, "wick length"}, 1, 
  100}, {{d, 6.8, "wick diameter"}, 1, 8}, {c, 1/60, 
  1/30}, {{ϵ, 0.5, "porosity"}, 0.3, 
  0.9}, {{Rb, 100, "fiber radius"}, 10, 
  200}, {{θ, 70, "contact angle"}, 0, 
  90}, {{ϕ, 90, "wick orientation"}, 0, 90}]
```

Note that the parameters at the beginning could also have been defined within Manipulate.